# grok pattern to extract data from log message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Recently I have started analysing ELK stack for log processing. In this I need to get some data out of my log message as fields to make this logs more productive.
Sample log message:

```
05:25:11,405 DEBUG ClassName:? - Start of some data like ^Akey1=value1^Akey2=value2^Akey3=value3....keyN=valueN
```

How can i get value of key2 into a field using grok.
 my attempt as belows:

```
%{TIME:timestamp}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:level}.*key2.*
```

Not sure how should i save key2's value
Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: is your classname in format com.example.classname and do you need question mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get value2 you can use:

```
%{TIME:timestamp}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{GREEDYDATA}key2=%{GREEDYDATA:key2}\^A
```

You can try it here: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks alpert..What should be used instead of WORD if value2 is alphanumeric with mixed characters basically the break between key value pair is specified by "^A" character

Comment: Updated my answer. GREEDYDATA will match everything until ^A

Comment: its taking everything till the end including key3=value3 and so on till the end

Comment: Ok Maybe the sample text that i've provided is not the exact message that i see..so I'll figure out grok pattern for that based on your above inputs..but thanks for the solution

Comment: Comment please if you will need further help